# Passing down symbol from a for loop to an if statement

Tags: java, if-statement, for-loop

It seems that a symbol in a "for loop" is local to the loop itself.
Is there any way to pass the information about what the symbol is currently representing down to, for example, an if statement?

For example, this generates an error:

```
int[] myAry = {1, 2, 3};
for (int i : myAry)
  if (i == 2);
    System.out.println(i);
```

While this doesn't:

```
int[] myAry = {1, 2, 3};
for (int i : myAry)
  if (i == 2);
    System.out.println("Match found!");
```

Comment: Your code seems pretty bad. Why do you add those if statements if you don't plan on using them ? You know the semicolon terminates the if statement, I hope ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both code snippets are wrong, and should be :

```
if (i == 2)
    System.out.println(i);
```

and

```
if (i == 2)
    System.out.println("Match found!");
```

There shouldn't be a semi colon after the condition.

The first snippet results in a compilation error since `System.out.println(i);` is outside the loop, so `i` is undefined.

The second snippet doesn't cause a compilation error (since it doesn't attempt to access `i`), but it is executed regardless of the result of the evaluation of the if condition, since it is outside the for loop.

Answer (score 2):

Some ways:

- Ensure single executable block after `for` if you wish to use no braces.

  ```
  int[] myAry = {1, 2, 3};
  for (int i : myAry)
    if (i == 2) // Remove the semi-colon. Seems inadvertently added.
        System.out.println(i);
  ```
- Use braces.

  ```
  int[] myAry = {1, 2, 3};
  for (int i : myAry){
    if (i == 2); // Assuming this was purposeful, seems unlikely though.
        System.out.println(i);
  }
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Your first code is basically:

```
int[] myAry = {1, 2, 3};
for (int i : myAry){
  if (i == 2){}
}
    System.out.println(i);
```

So, indeed, i doesn't exist in the scope where you try to print it. Either declare i outside of the for loop, or place your brackets the way you need them to be.